# Log Likelihood Converting from Sum Notation to Matrix Notation

Tags: generalized-linear-model, likelihood

I have found the log likelihood of a poisson GLM with the canonical link function to be $$\sum_{i=1}^n  y_i \eta_i  - exp(\eta_i) - log(y_i!) $$ Where $\eta = X \beta $. My question is how can I rewrite this sum into matrix notation?

Comment: You have now deleted two Qs in two days, why? It is almost always better to let questions stand ...

Comment: As it stands, you cannot really rewrite this into matrix notation, directly, since the expression is nonlinear ... what one can do, is approximate the likelihood quadratically around a trial solution, the maximizer then has the form of weighted linear regression for some calculated variables. Is that what you want?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I usually delete my post if I manage to solve the problem myself and it hasn't received an answer. I don't know if GLM's are perhaps not a very popular topic here, buy all my (quite straightforward and elementary) GLM related questions have received very little attention.

Comment: If you could answer it yourself, it is better to self-answer the Q. About glm's that is a popular topic here, look at [tag:generalized-linear-model] and browse some of the higher-voted posts, you will observe that those questions generally come with some context and more details than in your two posts. When a question lingers on without activty, try to better it, details, plots, ...